# How to share functionality between Polymer elements in the right way?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, composition

[Polymer behaviors](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors) are great. But sometimes I need to share a single function/method across multiple elements. I don't need lifecycle callbacks, declared properties, etc that comes with behaviors.

I do not know the architecture of Polymer well enough to know:

1. the best way and place (in life-cycle callbacks?) to add shared methods to custom elements
2. when it is better to extend the `Polymer.Base`?

**Example 1:**

Let's say we want to add a method for lazy-listening that will attach event listeners to elements `afterNextRender`:

```
Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender(this, function() {
    // add event listeners
});
```

As Monica explains in [Practical lessons from a year of building web components - Google I/O 2016](https://youtu.be/zfQoleQEa4w?t=23m30s) Polymer's `listeners` object should be avoided for elements that might be created in large numbers.

**Example 2**

Following her example, now we want to add ripple effects or control behaviors to elements only when they are hovered/active/focused and remove it when otherwise. This functionality will be needed by many elements.

**Example 3, functions from external libraries such as lodash**

Comment: Can you provide a concrete problem you try to solve?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer added examples :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short note for my own question for the time being.

### All elements: `Polymer.Base`

Polymer uses `Base`'s `_addFeature` method to extend the `Base` prototype which is the prototype of all Polymer elements (side note: `_addFeature` method itself uses `Base`'s `extend` method internally). This is the deepest level for extending Polymer Elements.

### Specific element type: element constructor object as well as Behaviors

**Behaviors** are shared between all elements of a specific type. They are applied in element **registration** time. And of course methods in the constructor object also goes to element type's proto.

### Specific to an element instance: everything else

Other methods defined from element creation onward are specific to that element instance. Also if you use `Polymer.Base.create(tag, obj)`, all the properties and methods in the `obj` will be applied to the created element (using `in` keyword i.e. no accessors). Hence, that `obj` could be shared between different element instances depending on the context.

### Conclusion

The standard way Polymer creators wanted us to share methods (and a lot more) between different element types is using **Behaviors**. However, if you have a feature that all or most elements use, extending `Polymer.Base` is a good option.